# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio starts then suddenly fails to launch

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed Sql Server 2014 Express then I have installed Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2018. Every thing worked fine and I created a database. SUDDENLY I tried to open Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2018, and the start popup appears and then disappears without launching the application and without any error message. Any help? how to launch Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2018?

Comment: Help us help you. If you were trying to help someone solve this problem, what information would you like to have?

Comment: how to lunch microsoft sql server management studio 2018?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reinstalling mssms?